# Netzke basepack. Need advice with multi uploading fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, netzke

Is there any easy way to include the multiupload feature to NetzkeFormView or GridView(AddInForm)?

My current image uloading field with carrierwave is:

```
    {:name => :image_link, :xtype => :displayfield, :display_only => true, :getter => lambda { |r| %Q(<a href='#{r.image.url}'>Download</a>) if r.image.url }},
    {:name => :image, :field_label => "Upload image", :xtype => :fileuploadfield, :getter => lambda { |r| "" }, :display_only => true}
```

Comment: Did you get any progress on this?